# lack of gz files when using tinyme with compressor in Internet Explorer

Tags: tinymce

I remark that when using tinyMce editor with compressor plugin, there are some gz files created in tinymce folder. When I delete them and load again the page with editor in Firefox, gz file is created again. But it is not happening when loading page with IE. 
Is it reasonable? Does it mean that IE is not using compressor plugin? Has anyone faced that?

Any reply appreciated.